# I get a "no default or ui configuration directive found" on boot

Tags: boot, live-usb, usb-drive

> **No default or UI configuration directive found.**

I get this error when I tried to reboot Ubuntu with the DiskOnKey flash drive.

Answer (score 0):

There are possible two causers for this:

**Cause 1:** The flash drive is formatted with NTFS or FAT32 
**Solution**: Format it using FAT16 (or only FAT).

**Cause 2:** There is a folder `/isolinx` and the files `/isolinx/isolinux.bin` and `/isolinx/isolinux.cfg` on your flash drive 
**Solution:** Just rename all the above folders and files to `syslinux`